# type error with LabelEncoder.fit_transform()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I was playing with the Titanic dataset on Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data), and I want to use LabelEncoder from sklearn.preprocessing to transform Sex, originally labeled as 'male' or 'female' into '0' or '1'. I had the following four lines of code,

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
df['Sex'] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
```

But when I ran it I received the following error message:

```
TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

the error comes from line 4, i.e.,

```
df['Sex'] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
```

I wonder what went wrong here. Although I know I could also do the transformation using map, which might be even simpler, but I still want to know what's wrong with my usage of LabelEncoder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using following [link to sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). LabelEncoder is a utility class and need to create the object with `LabelEncoder()`:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df['Sex'] = le.fit_transform(df['Sex'])
```

Testing with example:

```
# create test series
gender = pd.Series(['male', 'female', 'male'])

le = LabelEncoder()
transformed_val = le.fit_transform(gender)

# checking result after using label encoder
print(transformed_val)
```

Results:

```
[1 0 1]
```

Comment: I see what the problem is. I should either use LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['Sex'])  or le.fit_transform(df['Sex']) after setting le = LabelEncoder(). I was missing the () after LabelEncoder in my code. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding` .

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing the `()` which initializes a `LabelEncoder` instance.

This will work: `LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['Sex'])`

Having said that, 0p3n5ourcE's example is more conventional, and also a cleaner way to handle objects.

Comment: Yes, I now realized the problem. Thank you!